# Schedule tasks with dynamic time rails 4

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-4, scheduled-tasks

One of the parameters of my model at the create method is scheduled_time to create at, i want the model to be added to the database only when the scheduled time is arrived. how can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

guessing could use `sidekiq` (https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) to facilitate creating executing a method at a particular point in time:

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Getting-Started